# Discord.JS How I send a message to all members in server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Discord version 12.

```
const membersfetch = message.guild.members.fetch();
membersfetch.forEach((member) => member.send("Hello"))
```

^^ It has a bug. The console says:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null`

Send message to all members in server. The message is `Hello`

```
if(message.content === 'sentallmessage'){
 message("Hello")
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Members needs to be cached i believe

Answer (score 0):

[GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) `fetch` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with as first parameter a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) (if only one member) or a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

To get all members fetched you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) `then` method like that to execute your `forEach` loop only when all members are actually fetched :

```js
message.guild.members.fetch().then(membersfetch => {
    membersfetch.forEach((member) => member.send("Hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Success Version

```js
message.guild.members.fetch().then(membersfetch => {
    membersfetch.forEach((member) => member.send("Hello"));
})
```

or

```js
if(message.content === 'sentallmessage'){
 message.guild.members.fetch().then(membersfetch => {
 membersfetch.forEach((member) => member.send("Hello"));
})
}
```